# Is there a daemon installed in the package here .deb?

Tags: kubuntu, lubuntu

How to find out what is installed in the package .deb via the command line?
(I'm trying to figure out if some daemon has been installed with the package.)

Comment: See which files are installed from the deb file with `dpkg -L <package name>`. You will be able to see if any `*.service` are installed. Then you can try `systemctl status <service name>` to see if the installed service is running.

Comment: did you write the command correctly ?

Comment: Yes, I wrote the command correctly. You have to enter you package name and service name. For instance: `dpkg -L apache2` lists four `.service` files. For one of them to check, if it is running, try `systemctl status apache-htcacheclean`.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.